# I can't delete an Outlet in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I know you're supposed to click the x in the connections inspector, but [the one I'm trying to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcRTs.png) is greyed out and I don't know why. Any ideas on how to delete the "View" outlet would be helpful! Sorry for the bad quality picture.

Comment: Can you try removing it from the starboard itself, and re-adding it?

Comment: @ILikeTau thank you! i needed to add a table view controller instead of a detail view controller with a table view.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, the "starboard" should be "storyboard".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete the view outlet. It is inherent to the view controller. Why would you *want* to delete it? If you could, you'd have a completely broken view controller. The storyboard is simply trying to save you from yourself (and it seems you *need* to be saved from yourself).